# Passing document href as an option in XProc

Tags: xslt, xproc

I have an XProc script that currently hardcodes document hrefs like this:

```xml
<p:xslt>
    <p:input port="source"/>
    <p:input port="stylesheet">
        <p:document href="/path/to/stylesheet.xsl"/>
    </p:input>
</p:xslt>
```

I would like to pass `/path/to/stylesheet.xsl` as an option to the xproc script, so in my declare-step I put:

```xml
<p:option name="stylePath" required="true"/>
```

but I still can't figure out how to replace the hardcoded href in `p:document` with the option value.

I'll be most grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what eventually worked for me:

1. Create a step to load the document with the option passed to it:

   ```xml
   <p:load name="getStylesheetSource">
     <p:with-option name="href" select="$stylePath" /> 
   </p:load>
   ```
2. Then, in the XSLT step, pipe the loaded stylesheet

   ```xml
   <p:xslt name="transform">
       <p:input port="source">
          <!-- etc. -->  
       </p:input>
       <p:input port="stylesheet">
          <p:pipe step="getStylesheetSource" port="result" /> 
       </p:input>
   </p:xslt>
   ```

With this setup, one can pass the `stylePath` option when invoking the XProc script without having to hard code the path.

Comment: In XProc 1 I think that is the way to go, in XProc 3 it might be easier.